# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un textarea haga un salto de linea cada cierta cantidad de caracteres?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo un `<textarea>` en un formulario, en el cual se escriben notas de la información añadida, la cuestión es que sí el usuario no le da manualmente <kbd>enter</kbd> no hace un salto de linea y la información queda totalmente recta, eso va a una tabla y esa tabla por acomodar ese texto, desacomoda la tabla, entonces sí hay una forma de hacerlo con js, jquery, he buscado pero no he logrado nada, sí me pudieran ayudar, se los agradecería.

Dejo el `HTML`

```html
<div class="form-group row ml-1 justify-content-center">
                <label for="nota" class="col-form-label">Nota:</label>
                <div class='col-sm-5 mr-3'>
                    <textarea name="nota" id="nota" class="form-control" cols="4" rows="3" maxlength="20"></textarea>
                </div>                                                
            </div>
```

Comment: En lugar de intentar dar un salto de línea en el `textarea`, creo que sería mejor idea darle un tamaño definido al campo de la tabla para que el texto se ajuste a el.

Comment: Sí, pero aún así se intenta ajustar por lo que le apliqué bootstrap, pero sí tienes una idea de como hacerlo, me ayudarias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes tener una variable que cuente los caracteres ingresados, una vez llegue a cierto limite que aplique un salto de linea automaticamente, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma.

En este ejemplo se inserta un salto de linea por cada 5 caracteres ingresados:

```js
var letras=0;

function check(e) {       
      tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
      if(tecla>32)
       letras++;
      if(letras==5){
        letras=0;
        document.getElementById("nota").value+='\n';
      }
      return true;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row ml-1 justify-content-center">
                <label for="nota" class="col-form-label">Nota:</label>
                <div class='col-sm-5 mr-3'>
                    <textarea name="nota" id="nota" class="form-control" cols="10" rows="5" onkeyup="check(event);"></textarea>
                </div>                                                
            </div>
```

Pero no considero que sea la mejor opción, si lo que introduces en el `<textarea>` son palabras y oraciones podrías hacerlo de esta otra forma:

En este ejemplo cuando introduces mas de 10 caracteres se aplicará el salto de linea, pero solo cuando se ingrese un espacio, de ese modo no tendrás palabras cortadas como en el ejemplo anterior.

```js
var letras=0;

function check(e) {       
      tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
      if(tecla>32)
       letras++;
      if(letras>10&&tecla==32){
        letras=0;
        document.getElementById("nota").value+='\n';
      }
      return true;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row ml-1 justify-content-center">
     <label for="nota" class="col-form-label">Nota:</label>
     <div class='col-sm-5 mr-3'>
         <textarea name="nota" id="nota" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="5" onkeyup="check(event);"></textarea>
     </div>                                                
</div>
```

Puedes comprobarlo escribiendo texto y copiandolo en un block de notas, podrás ver que se introducen los saltos de linea.

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, está muy bueno tu método, perdona, y en cuanto a lo que me dijiste que dejara el campo de la tabla un tamaño definido para que no se mueva, aunque le tengo aplicado bootstrap y el lo hace automático

Comment: @DaxTter77, no te preocupes, tu defines la cantidad de caracteres según el tamaño que te da bootstrap, solo debes cambiar esta linea `if(letras>10&&tecla==32){`, en lugar de 10 pon el numero de caracteres que creas conveniente.

Comment: Sí, pero en cuanto a lo que me dijiste para el campo de la tabla que quede fijo, sí se acomode el texto solo en ese campo sin que se extienda, como me recomendarías hacerlo?

Comment: @DaxTter77 ¿dices que quieres que el textarea se quede fijo y no pueda cambiarse de tamaño manualmente? lo puedes hacer poniendo `resize: none;` en el estilo, pon `textarea{  resize: none; }` y eso es todo.

Comment: y en cuanto a la columna en la tabla? se puede hacer lo mismo?

Comment: @DaxTter77 el `resize: none;` es para que no pueda moverse ni el alto ni el ancho del textarea, ¿o a que te refieres exactamente?

Comment: A que sí dejo lineal lo que se escribe en el textarea, cuando mande esa información en la tabla, también se acomode

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96321/discussion-between-the-breaker-and-daxtter77).

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría más hacer el salto de línea al presionar una tecla especial como por ejemplo la tecla del punto debido a que usar una cantidad n de caracteres podría partir palabras y esto afectaría la lectura del usuario.

Usando el evento `keyup()` y las propiedades `key` y `keyCode` puedes resolver tu problema:

```js
$("#nota").keyup(function(e){
  if(e.key == '.' && e.keyCode == 190){
    var valor = $(this).val();
     
    $(this).val(valor += '\n\n');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group row ml-1 justify-content-center">
    <label for="nota" class="col-form-label">Nota:</label>
    <div class='col-sm-5 mr-3'>
        <textarea name="nota" id="nota" class="form-control" cols="4" rows="3" maxlength="20"></textarea>
    </div>                                                
</div>
```

Comment: Pero, dado el caso de que no haya punto sino un párrafo como tal y necesito que haga el salto después de que se llene digamos una linea del `<textarea>` pues ahí estaría en las mismas

Comment: @DaxTter77 pero de alguna forma tienes que saber cuándo partir el párrafo y cuando no, entonces no te entiendo

Comment: Exactamente como se hace en este `<textarea>` para comentar, sí se acaba el espacio, el baja, así lo necesito, o sino que se acomode en la tablita de tal forma de que no me dañe nada